# Flatten a list with sublists and strings

Tags: python, list

How can I flatten a list of lists into a list?

For ex,:

```
Input_List = [['a', 'b'],'c','d',['e', 'f']]
```

Expectation:

```
Final_List = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Comment: Please check your code for typos!

Comment: The input shown is not a list of lists. You have lists **and scalars**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this working only for -> multdimensional at the same dimension

```
from itertools import chain
 
ini_list = [[1, 2, 3],
            [3, 6, 7],
            [7, 5, 4]]
             
print ("initial list ", str(ini_list))
 
flatten_list = list(chain.from_iterable(ini_list))
 
print ("final_result", str(flatten_list))
```

[image]

---

If some arrays isn't nested  - then

```
def flatten(something):
    if isinstance(something, (list, tuple, set, range)):
        for sub in something:
            yield from flatten(sub)
    else:
        yield something
            
test = flatten(ini_list)
list(test)
```

Comment: Now try this with the input in the question

Comment: yes - that's true - i edited the question

Comment: The input list contains mixed types, strings and lists, so this won't work.

Comment: You check the second func?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to check the type of each list item to determine if it is merely a value to output or a sublist to expand.

Using a list comprehension:

```
Input_List = [['a', 'b'],'c','d',['e', 'f']]
Final_List = [v for i in Input_List for v in (i if isinstance(i,list) else [i])]
print(Final_List)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Or using an iterative loop:

```
Final_List = []
for item in Input_List:
    if isinstance(item,list): Final_List.extend(item)
    else:                     Final_List.append(item)
print(Final_List)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Or using a recursive function if you need to flatten all levels of nested lists:

```
def flat(A):
    return [v for i in A for v in flat(i)] if isinstance(A,list) else [A]

Input_List = [['a', 'b'],'c','d',['e2', 'f3',['x','y']]]
Final_List = flat(Input_List)
print(Final_List)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e2', 'f3', 'x', 'y']
```